# Настройка размеров диалогового окна Android

Tags: android, android-dialog

Создаю диалоговое окно наследуя `DialogFragment`.  С помощью  `setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0)` убираю заголовок диалога и после этого он стает по размеру моего лейаута, который я задаю `DialogFragment`.
Нужно задать диалогу размер, побывал задавать размер в размере леяаута но это не помогло.

**Код диалога:**

```
public class TaskNameDialofFragment extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_task_name_dialog, null);
        getDialog().getWindow().setDimAmount(0.6f);

        return  v;
    }
}
```

**Его леяут:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_name_dialog_title"
        style="@style/task_name_dialog_title"
        android:text="@string/task_name_dialog_title"
        />

    <EditText
        style="@style/task_name_edit_field"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/task_name_cancel_button"
            style="@style/task_name_dialog_button"
            android:background="@drawable/round_task_name_dialog_cancel_button"
            android:text="@string/button_cancel"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/task_name_ok_button"
            style="@style/task_name_dialog_button"
            android:background="@drawable/round_task_name_dialog_ok_button"
            android:text="@string/button_ok"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Изменение `layout_height`, `layout_width,` в корневом леяуте ничего не дало.

Как можно изменить размер диалога?

Comment: Слово "леяут" просто убило))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.setLayout(width, height);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Ps: или в `onStart()`

Comment: спасибо ) помогло!!